# Toggling a p.class in jQuery but it keeps grabbing an image outside of the tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, toggle

I have a series of p tags that I want to have toggle in jQuery. I have an image slightly outside the p tags. When I write the toggle function and execute it, the animation toggles both the declared p tag and the image that is outside of the p tag.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nF5qU/1/

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="toggle" id="toggleIt"><a>CLICK ME</a></div>
<div class="nav">
    <div class="One">
        <img src="pipeline/img/right.png" class="imgFunc"> 
        <p class="hideMe">Suspendisse cursus dapibus luctus knowing. 
            <br />
        <span>website.com</span></p>
    </div> 
    <!-- -->
<div class="nav">
    <div class="One">
        <img src="pipeline/img/right.png" class="directionalImg"> 
        <p class="hideMe">Suspendisse cursus dapibus luctus knowing. 
            <br />
        <span>website.com</span></p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.directionalImg{
position: absolute;
padding-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
}
.One{
margin-top: 125px;
}
.One p{
font-size: 9pt;
margin-left: 22px;
}
.One p span{
font-style: italic;
color: #999;
padding-right: 10px;
}
.toggleIt{
margin-top: 98px;
position: absolute;
font-size: 20pt;
}
```

​

jQuery

```
$("#toggleIt").click(function() {
$(".hideMe").toggle(500);
$("#toggleIt").animate({
    "left": "400px"
}, 0);
$(".nav").animate({
    "left": "400px"
}, 0);
});​
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this? Is it because my image is 'absolute' ? I tried writing the function as p.hideMe instead of just .hideMe and nothing happens. Any help is greatly appreciated.

***EDIT: Sorry I was writing this quickly and forgot to close tags and place a '.' in front of hideMe. I wasn't copying and pasting over so I assure you all tags are closed in the actual document.***

Comment: maybe because your html is invalid/broken? you are missing quote marks inside your first opening div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing quote mark causing html to be broken

```
<div id="slideFunction> <--
```

and your you're missing the period for class selector

```
$("#slideFunction").click(function () {
    $(".hideMe").toggle(500); // <-- you were missing the period
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6NjX/

Comment: Sorry I made those mistakes here I assure you they are correct on the actual document. Sorry abou that.

Comment: @rsr9000 then it should work fine.. did you look at the fiddle?

Comment: Yeah the fiddle works great. However it still grabs the image on mine. I should mention that I also have have these function executing as well 

' $("#slideFuntion").animate({"left": "400px"}, 0);
 $(".divMover").animate({"left": "400px"}, 0); '

Comment: if you could create a fiddle to replicate your issue, it would be easier to troubleshoot what problem you are running into

Comment: the image is still there.. it's just directly over the other image.

Comment: It's your toggle that is causing your "img" appear to be animating.  it isn't.  toggle removes the the space the element takes up too.  You can probably achieve what you want with animating opacity instead of toggling. http://jsfiddle.net/k8PXP/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried closing your image tag?

```
<img src="images/pic.png" class="imgOne" />
```

And you're not closing your first div tag properly

```
<div id="slideFunction">
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gS7DB/1/

Answer (score 0):

Besides your html problems like missing quotes on your div class:

```
<div id="slideFunction">click here to hide paragraph</div> <!-- instead of: <div id="slideFunction>click here to hide paragraph</div> -->
```

Missing the end tags from your img tag,

```
<img src="images/pic.png" class="imgOne"/>  <!-- instead of <img src="images/pic.png" class="imgOne"> -->
```

You are not selecting anything with this line of code:

```
$("hideMe").toggle(500);
```

Which should be:

```
$(".hideMe").toggle(500);
```